# Microsoft Velocity caching used outside of ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching, appfabric

Can Velocity be used outside of ASP.NET and/or IIS? We would to do a standard class libery and would like to do caching and wondering if this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing in AppFabric (Velocity was the codename, it was dropped last year when it shipped as part of Windows Server AppFabric) that's specific to ASP.NET is the session state provider. If you want to use AppFabric in any other kind of solution (WinForms, WCF), then it's just another tool and you can go right ahead :-)